# how to print the longest of three strings?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, string-length

Is there a quick way to select the longest of three strings (s1,s2,s3) using if/else method?

I'm using Java

I have tried using something like this

```
if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
    System.out.println(s1); ...
```

but did not get it right.

Comment: `System.out.println` looks an awful lot like Java, not C#...

Comment: Probably is java, since in C# string length is a property. Making it s1.Length, s1.length() implies the java method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to program all possible combinations with an if-else construct, as the complexity will grow exponentially if you add more strings.

This solution works well for a small number of strings with a linear complexity:

```
string longest = s1;
if (s2.length() > longest.length()) {
    longest = s2;
}
if (s3.length() > longest.length()) {
    longest = s3;
}
System.out.println(longest);
```

For a lager number of strings, put them in collection and find the longest using a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use if, else if, else in C# (if you aren't actually using Java which it looks like you are) to handle this.

```
string current = str;

if(str2.Length > current.Length)
{
    current = str2;
}
if (str3.Length > current.Length)
{
    current = str3;
}
```

Unless using if/else is a requirement of this code, using a collection and LINQ will be a cleaner option.

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>
{
    "str",
    "strLen",
    "strLength"
};

// This aggregate will return the longest string in a list.
string longestStr = strList.Aggregate("", (max, cur) => max.Length > cur.Length ? max : cur);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            string a = "123";
            string b = "1322";
            string c = "122332";
            if (a.Length > b.Length && a.Length > c.Length)
            {
               
                    Console.WriteLine(a);                    
            }
            else if (b.Length > c.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if/then/else constructs Java is same as C#. you can use solutions above. LINQ is like Streams in Java. In Java you can code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  printtLongest ("VampireApi","C#-Api","Java Api");
}

public static void printtLongest(String ... strings){
     java.util.Arrays
      .stream(strings)
      .sorted(java.util.Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed())
      .findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create an array and input a string into each part of the array(can do this through loop or manually add- `String[] st= new st String[];`  then you can:  `st[0]="aaa"; st[1]="eff"`... after this you can use a loop which takes the current length of the string at the array[i] and use a variable max(which will start at 0) which keep the highest length using the Math.max() function.
if the length(which is an integer) is larger then max then you save the string in a string variable and the loop will go through every string In your array and will update the max if needed. after this you can either return or print the string which is the longest.
this is one of many ways. or you could do three if's to check. this method would work great with larger amount of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not using if-else as the OP asked, but a cleaner solution is this:

```
void longest(String a, String b, String c) {
    String[] triplet = {a, b, c};
    Arrays.sort(triplet, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
    System.out.println(triplet[2]);
}
```